# Laravel v5.4.15 on Heroku: all routes but / stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, routes

I want to say that I googled this and read a LOT of posts on similar issues, however, in reading what I've found, I haven't found any posts that quite apply to this situation.

I have my code set in a dropbox sync'd folder with Heroku. (apache cedar-14) I did a a few updates today and something has gone awry and I need help tracking it down.

The symptoms: on my domain, only the / route resolves. All else result in a 404

The same code set, however, running via a 'php artisan serve' session, is serving everything up just fine.

I did notice, however, that running a 'php artisan route:list' results in these errors:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Access level to
    App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be public (as in 
    class App\Http\Controllers\Controller) in 
    \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php on line 10

    [2017-03-12 19:58:31] local.ERROR: 
    Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Access level to 
    App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be public 
    (as in class App\Http\Controllers\Controller) in 
    \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main}

    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Access level to 
    App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create() must be public 
    (as in class App\Http\Controllers\Controller)
```

I also noticed that if I comment out Auth::routes() in web.php, 'php artisan route:list' did not return those errors.

The work I did today on the site included creating and updating views and controller files. I did only one thing related to auth (LoginController.php change below):

```
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        //return view('auth.login');
        return view('v1.public_pages.home-login');
    }
```

I'm happy to provide more information if you give me a sense of what's needed to diagnose this.

I've been using Laravel for only ~1 month and it's been a steep learning curve.

Two last pieces of information.

1) I made a fresh laravel build and compared files.

I had "extra stuff" in my Controller.php and so I removed most of it because it wasn't necessary. In the process of doing so, I stopped receiving the error messages from 'php artisan route:list' above.  All of my routes are listed.

However, the routes still do not work.  They return 404 errors.

2) I feared that Dropbox might be the cause so I unlinked it and made a git repository instead.  Alas, no change.

Please help!  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide your route/web.php content?

Comment: You can see the output of php artisan route:list from heroku (which exactly matches the same command run locally) here:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88157469/heroku_routes.txt

Comment: and I added routes/web.php just in case here:   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88157469/web.php

Comment: "I have my code set in a dropbox sync'd folder with Heroku." You what?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassed.  This turned out to be a pretty-URLs issue which is covered in the Laravel installation documentation.

Turns out the .htaccess file was eliminated from the git repository and hence, it all stopped working.

The quick check for this for anyone who may benefit and save days of wondering, is to see if links like:  yourdomain/index.php/route-that-should-work

If it works, you've got an .htaccess issue.  And on heroku, it might be an apache_app.conf file issue.

I hope this saves others some time at least.